# APL - Import dll

Tags: apl

I'm going to take a chance here and see if anyone can help me.  I'm making use of a simulation package written in APL.  I need to do some machine learning on data and would like to make use of existing libraries available for C++ and compile into a dll that an be called from APL.

Any idea how to import a dll and call functions from APL?

Comment: Which version of APL are you using?

Comment: It is not Dyalog.  No idea what version it is

Answer (score 2):

In [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), you just need to use the `⎕NA` system function.

For example, `math.dll` might be a library of mathematical functions containing a function `divide`. To associate the APL name `div` with this external function:

```
      'div' ⎕NA 'F8 math|divide I4 I4'
```

where `F8` and `I4`, specify the types of the result and arguments expected by divide. The association has the effect of establishing a new function: `div` in the workspace, which when called, passes its arguments to `divide` and returns the result.

```
      )fns
div
      div 10 4
2.5
```

`⎕NA` is [fully documented](http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/na.htm), but do not hesitate to drop into [the Stack Exchange chat room for APL](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) if you need further assistance.

You can also [search GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=language%3Aapl+in%3Afile+%E2%8E%95na&type=Code) to see some examples of `⎕NA` in use.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help.  However the software is not using Dyalog.  I'm not sure which version, but it must be ancient as the application is in existence for almost 40 years.  It is called Metsim

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the METSIM archive. It is definitely written in APL*PLUS.

Unfortunately, [APL+Win](http://apl2000.com/), as it is called now, does not have any online documentation that I know of.

However, it does have [`⎕NA`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.apl/Z63Rzthf6hw) and also something called [`⎕WCALL`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.apl/WnN39CP1dqY).

You may need to await other answers, or [contact APL2000](http://apl2000.com/contact.php) for assistance.